How to avoid duplicated entries while seeding a database using typeorm-extension
In a NestJS with TypeORM I tried to seed a MariaDB database using typeorm-extension package. The problem is that sometimes while running the script to seed the database it creates duplicated entries which throws an exception and stopping the database seeding.
country.factory.ts
import { Country } from 'src/locations/countries/entities/country.entity';
import { setSeederFactory } from 'typeorm-extension';

export default setSeederFactory(Country, (faker) => {
  const country = new Country({
    name: faker.location.country(),
    status: faker.datatype.boolean(),
  });

  return country;
});

country.seeder.ts
import { Country } from 'src/locations/countries/entities/country.entity';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { Seeder, SeederFactoryManager } from 'typeorm-extension';
import { quantities } from '../quantities';

export default class CountrySeeder implements Seeder {
  public async run(
    dataSource: DataSource,
    factoryManager: SeederFactoryManager,
  ): Promise<void> {
    await dataSource.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
    await dataSource.query('ALTER TABLE countries AUTO_INCREMENT=1;');

    const countryFactory = factoryManager.get(Country);
    await countryFactory.saveMany(quantities.countries);

    await dataSource.query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
  }
}

I used an array to store the already created entries to compare the new ones but did not work or i was using it the wrong way
